# Two ListViews & ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm so close here and I've tried many things but cannot get it to work.  I have two listviews here. What I want is for each listview to show its ENTIRE content.  I don't want the listviews scrollable. I want the Scrollview that holds the listviews scrollable.  The closest i've been able to get it (which is wrong) is so that each listview is scrollable.  This means that each listview only shows like 1 1/2 cells. I would think this would be a dirt simple task but Android has some quirky things going on.

So again, each list view shows its entire content, even if that content height goes past the screen.  Then all I have to do is scroll down to see the second list view which shows its entire content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_weight="10"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCCCCC"
android:text="@string/alerts_top_title"
android:gravity="center"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</TextView>
<ListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/cameraListAlerts" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_weight="10"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#CCCCCC"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:text="@string/alerts_bottom_title">
</TextView>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="8dp">
</LinearLayout>
<Button
android:id="@+id/addRecipient"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="@string/addRecipient"/>

<ListView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/recipientListAlerts" >
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `ListView`s don't go in `ScrollView`s.  Populate your lists in a LinearLayout programmatically instead of using the `ListView`s.  That's exactly what you want.

Comment: I knew that one was going to be thrown out there. Isn't there a way I can just get this to work without doing so much work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're going to spend far more time and energy trying to get this to work if it ever does.  `ListView`s exist to handle long lists that require too many resources to be drawn at one time.  They recycle the row Views when you scroll through them to allow for a snappy load.  You're trying to ditch that functionality, thereby making your use of the `ListView` essentially pointless.

Populating a `LinearLayout` programmatically is no big deal at all.  Do you have an XML file for your rows?  Inflate it for each new row as you run an extremely simple `for` loop through your Array or `while` loop through your Cursor, binding the data, and adding it to your `LinearLayout`.

Done.  No scrolling issues... it's all handled by the ScrollView like it should be.

Comment: I have tons of code that works through my custom adapters and event handlers (for item clicks and such). How would I incorporate your method without doing heavy modification of all that stuff?

Comment: So you would rather force ListViews to do something they weren't designed for? It is a well known fact to anyone with a little ListView experience that they cannot function properly within a ScrollView of the same orientation. I would suggest you watch this video from Google IO 2010: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: Well what kind of item clicks? Row clicks? I'd just set the `android:onClick` in the row's XML to some method, then use `setTag(index [array] or id [cursor])` in the loop so that you can then call `getTag()` on the View that's passed to the method you set in the onClick attribute and discern which item was clicked.  Then you can act accordingly.  There may be a more elegant way to do that.  For other Views within that View (say, clicking on an image in a row describing a contact), I'd create a really quick custom View.  It may sound like a lot of work, but it's a much better approach.

Comment: If you really have that many items in your list, you should be using one `ListView` without the `ScrollView`.  I'm still not sure whether you're working with Arrays or Cursors, but Arrays are easy to combine.  Cursors can use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorJoiner.html

Comment: Thanks for the help people. What this means to me in any form is that its going to be quite a bit of work here. iPhone two tableviews on one screen, two tableview controllers and two datasources. Whammo, desired result in less than 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private ListView first, second;
private String check="";
String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Afghanistan", "Albania",
        "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla",
        "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia",
        "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahrain",
        "Montserrat", "Morocco",
        "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "NepalA",
        "Montserrat", "MoroccoF",
        "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "NepalB",
        "Montserrat", "MoroccoD",
        "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "NepalC",

};

String[] COUNTRIES1 = new String[] { "Martinique",
        "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mayotte", "Mexico", "Micronesia",
        "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montserrat", "Morocco",
        "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", };
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    first = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.firstlist);
    second = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.secondlist);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, COUNTRIES1);

    first.setAdapter(adapter);
    second.setAdapter(adapter1);

     second.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
         check="second";
     return false;
     }
      });

     first.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
             check="first";
         return false;
         }
          });
     first.setOnScrollListener(newScrollEvent);
     second.setOnScrollListener(newScrollEvent);
}

private OnScrollListener newScrollEvent = new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("first")){
         System.out.println("first");

         if (first.getChildAt(0) != null) {
         Rect r1 = new Rect();
         first.getChildVisibleRect(first.getChildAt(0), r1, null);
         second.setSelectionFromTop(first.getFirstVisiblePosition(),
         r1.top);
         }
        }
        else if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("second")){
        if (second.getChildAt(0) != null) {
         Rect r1 = new Rect();
         second.getChildVisibleRect(second.getChildAt(0), r1, null);
         first.setSelectionFromTop(second.getFirstVisiblePosition(),
         r1.top);
         }
         }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

create scrollview at run time like this way.

```
 //find parent xml layout
         LinearLayout lL1 =(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pro_scroll);

        //Create ScrollView programatically 
            ScrollView _scrollView  = new ScrollView(appContext);
           _scrollView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
           _scrollView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        ViewGroup layout=new LinearLayout(appContext);
                           layout.setLayoutParams(new   ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

//add scrollview to layout 
                           layout.addView(_scrollView);
//add layout to xml parent layout
                           lL1.addView(layout);
```